# I want to dynamically create python code based on values in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of field name in a database table (my actual list is 15+ in length and can vary)

```
flds = ["foo", "bar", "foobar"]
```

I also have field name in a function that correspond to those values

```
foo = "red"
bar = ""
foobar = "green"
```

I have code be low that is the same for each variable

```
sql = "UPDATE table SET a = 1 "

if foo == "":
    sql = sql + ", foo = NULL"
elif foo is not None:
    sql = sql + ",foo = " + foo
if bar == "":
    sql = sql + ", bar = NULL"
elif foo is not None:
    sql = sql + ",bar= " + bar***
if foobar == "":
    sql = sql + ", foobar = NULL"
elif foo is not None:
    sql = sql + ",foobar= " + foobar
```

The code is the exact same for each variable in the list and I don't want to have to write this segment of code for each variable every time the list changes; I want a way to create it dynamically based on the current values in the list.

I have tried using the exec() command

```
for fld in flds:
    tmp_fld = f"{fld}" 
    # the actual value now of tmp_fld is "foo"
    exec(f"tmp_fld_val = {tmp_fld}")
    # I want the value of tmp_fld_val to be "red" but no joy here
    if tmp_fld_val == "":
        sql = f"{sql} ,{tmp_fld} = NULL"
    elif tmp_fld_val is not None:
        sql = f"{sql} ,{tmp_fld} = '{tmp_fld_val}'"
```

Comment: Completely wrong approach. Think in terms of dicts and lists which hold your values, and looping over those things to dynamically create the SQL string. Don't dynamically create code which creates code, that's just more and more nonsensical.

Comment: Yeah, Python isn't lisp... Trying to generate code _can_ work, but really it's just harmful I'd just evaluate using f-strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so here's my situation multiple tables, multiple field names in each.  I get data from web api and save into class.  I then update database with some of those values.  I don't want to have to duplicate code for every table and every variable in that table.  so here is my solution based on Greg provided me above

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
import pymysql

# List of field names
flds = ["foo", "bar", "foobar"]

@dataclass
class MyFooBarClass:   
   key: str
   foo: str = field(default=None)
   bar: str = field(default=None)
   foobar: str = field(default=None)
   
   def __connect__(self):
      ...
      return self.cursor
      
   def __disconnect__(self):
      self.con.close()
      
   def execute(self, sql, values):
      self.__connect__()
      result = self.cur.execute(sql, values)
      self.con.commit()
      self.__disconnect__()
      return result
   
   def update(self):
      sql, values = self.get_update_sql()
      self.execute(sql, values)
      
   def get_update_sql(self):
      # init the values
      values = ()
      fld_values = {}
      # create the dictionary of values
      for fld in flds:
         exec(f"fld_values[fld] = self.{fld}")      

         # init the sql_cmd
         sql_cmd = "UPDATE   my_table " \
                   "SET      updated_on = SYSDATE() "
         for fld_name in flds:
            fld_val = fld_values.get(fld_name)
            if fld_val == "":
                sql_cmd += f", {fld_name} = NULL "
            elif fld_val is not None:
                sql_cmd += f", {fld_name} = %s "
                values += (f"{fld_val}",)
                
         sql_cmd += f" WHERE     db_cluster_resource_id = %s;"
         values += (f"{self.key}",)
```

Maybe an easier way to do it, but this works and saves me mucho coding

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use exec for it, just store these fields inside a dictionary and loop through them creating sql statements.

```
# List of field names
flds = ["foo", "bar", "foobar"]

# Dictionary mapping field names to their values
values = {
    "foo": "red",
    "bar": "",
    "foobar": "green"
}

# Initial SQL statement
sql = "UPDATE table SET a = 1"

# Iterate over the list of fields and construct the SQL dynamically
for fld in flds:
    value = values.get(fld)
    if value == "":
        sql += f", {fld} = NULL"
    elif value is not None:
        sql += f", {fld} = '{value}'"

print(sql)
```

Comment: much thanks, I knew it should be easy, just needed a set of different eyes

Comment: fyi, on a side note, I never realized I could do a += on strings, ... "old dog, new tricks"

Comment: Python makes working with strings easy, dynamic typing is a bliss if you don't care much about performance